# Convert String into array in sql/ power BI /excel

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I have a scenario to convert a field of data type varachar `03/28 8:00-7:30 03/29 8:00-7:30 03/30 8:00-6:00 04/02 8:00-7:30 04/03 8:00-7:30 04/04 8:00-7:30 04/05 8:00-7:30 04/06 8:00-7:30 04/07 8:00-6:00 04/09 8:00-7:30 04/10 8:00-7:30 04/11 8:00-7:30 04/12 8:00-7:30 04/13 8:00-7:30 04/14 8:00-3:00`

into an array using sql or power BI or excel using power query?

Data now looks like

```
Emp_ID  Emp_name date_hrs_operation

1             ABD           "03/28 8:00-7:30 03/29 8:00-7:30 03/30 8:00-6:00 04/02 8:00-7:30 04/03 8:00-7:30 04/04 8:00-7:30 04/05 8:00-7:30 04/06 8:00-7:30 04/07 8:00-6:00 04/09 8:00-7:30 04/10 8:00-7:30 04/11 8:00-7:30
04/12 8:00-7:30 04/13 8:00-7:30 04/14 8:00-3:00"
```

I need to be in this format,

```
Emp_ID  Emp_Name  date_hrs_operation

1             ABD             03/28 8:00-7:30

1             ABD             03/29 8:00-7:30

1             ABD              03/30 8:00-6:00

1             ABD              04/02 8:00-7:30
```

etc.. By any method can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you storing delimited data in your database in the first place? Also why are you storing date and time data without a year, and as a range? That date range column should be many rows, 2 columns (for the start and end times), and both be a strongly typed date and time data type.

Comment: Did any of the answers provided work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Im powerquery, if you have that long string in a column, the below code will split it in the desired method

Basically ... (a) split by space (b) add index (c) modify index to show 0/1 every other row using Number.Mod (d) filter for 0 and combine that column with a filter for 1 (e) remove extra columns (f) rename [not done here]

sample code to transform blue on right to green on left:

you can click select the two columns and merge them if you want

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column3", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column3"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Index modulo" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.Mod(_,2), Int64.Type}}),
Part1= Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectRows(#"Index modulo", each ([Index] = 0))),
Part2= Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectRows(#"Index modulo", each ([Index] = 1))),
combined=Table.FromColumns(Part1&Part2),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(combined,{"Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column8"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

optional merging of the two columns, use this ending instead:

```
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(combined,{"Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column8"}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Column3", "Column7"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in #"Merged Columns"
```

For a different, single step solution, right click ... split column .. by number of positions. Depends on if you can have the time data always have format hh:mm instead of h:mm before noon and hh:mm after noon.  For the sample data, which only has h:mm, using 16 characters works in a single step

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. This is what I did and it worked.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer as solved by toggling the checkmark next to the up/down arrows

Answer (score 0):

Another option in SQL Server is to use an ad-hoc tally/numbers table in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select A.Emp_ID
      ,A.Emp_name
      ,C.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Join  (Select Top 50 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) B
 Cross Apply ( values (substring([date_hrs_operation],(N*16)+1,16)) )C(date_hrs_operation)
 Where C.date_hrs_operation<>''
```

**Results**

```
Emp_ID  Emp_name    date_hrs_operation
1       ABD         03/28 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         03/29 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         03/30 8:00-6:00 
1       ABD         04/02 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/03 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/04 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/05 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/06 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/07 8:00-6:00 
1       ABD         04/09 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/10 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/11 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/12 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/13 8:00-7:30 
1       ABD         04/14 8:00-3:00
```

EDIT - Rather than a CROSS JOIN you can use an explicit join and remove the WHERE

```
...
 Join  (Select Top 100 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) B on N<=len([date_hrs_operation])/16
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One more method by using tokenization via XML/XQuery and mod operator.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Emp_ID INT, Emp_name VARCHAR(20), date_hrs_operation VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Emp_ID, Emp_name, date_hrs_operation) VALUES
(1, 'ABD', '03/28 8:00-7:30 03/29 8:00-7:30 03/30 8:00-6:00 04/02 8:00-7:30 04/03 8:00-7:30 04/04 8:00-7:30 04/05 8:00-7:30 04/06 8:00-7:30 04/07 8:00-6:00 04/09 8:00-7:30 04/10 8:00-7:30 04/11 8:00-7:30 04/12 8:00-7:30 04/13 8:00-7:30 04/14 8:00-3:00');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT Emp_ID, Emp_name
    , date_hrs_operation = t.c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') + ' ' +
        t.c.value('(/root/*[sql:column("seq.pos")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
   --, seq.pos   -- just to see
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(date_hrs_operation, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY t1.c.nodes('/root/*[position() mod 2 = 1]') AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.c.value('let $n := . return count(/root/*[. << $n[1]]) + 2','INT') AS pos
        ) AS seq;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+----------+--------------------+
| Emp_ID | Emp_name | date_hrs_operation |
+--------+----------+--------------------+
|      1 | ABD      | 03/28 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 03/29 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 03/30 8:00-6:00    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/02 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/03 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/04 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/05 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/06 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/07 8:00-6:00    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/09 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/10 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/11 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/12 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/13 8:00-7:30    |
|      1 | ABD      | 04/14 8:00-3:00    |
+--------+----------+--------------------+
```